# NgRx effect, ones failure occurs, does not accept new actions

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

```
@Injectable()
export class UserEffects {
  constructor(
    private store$: Store<fromRoot.State>,
    private actions$: Actions,
    private router: Router,
    private chatService: ChatService,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private db: AngularFireAuth,
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  @Effect()
  login$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(UserActions.LOGIN),
    switchMap((action: UserActions.LoginAction) =>
      from(this.db.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(action.payload.email, action.payload.password)),
    ),
    // switchMapTo(from(this.db.auth.currentUser.getIdToken())),
    switchMapTo(from(this.db.authState.pipe(
      take(1),
      switchMap((user)=>{
        if (user)
          return from(user.getIdToken());
        else
          return of(null);
      })
    ))),
    switchMap(token => this.http.post(environment.apiUrl + '/api/login', { token: token })),
    tap((response: any) => {
      if (response.valid === 'true') {

        localStorage.setItem('token', response.token);

        this.router.navigate(['dash']);

      }
    }),
    map(response => new UserActions.LoginSuccessAction({ response })),
    catchError(error => {
      return of({
        type: UserActions.LOGIN_FAILURE,
        payload: error
      });
    })
  );

  @Effect({ dispatch: false })
  loginSuccess$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(UserActions.LOGIN_SUCCESS),
    tap((action: UserActions.LoginSuccessAction) => {
      console.log("LOGIN_SUCCESS");
      console.log(action);
    }));

    @Effect({ dispatch: false })
    loginFailure$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(UserActions.LOGIN_FAILURE),
      tap((action: UserActions.LoginFailureAction)=>{
        console.log("LOGIN_FAILURE");
        console.log(action.payload.code);
      }));
}
```

Use case:
You are at a login page. You enter your username and password to call LoginAction. If all goes well, LoginSuccessAction should be called. Otherwise, LoginFailureAction should be called.

Everything works except one case:
  Once LoginFailureAction is called once, neither LoginSuccessAction nor LoginFailureAction will be called again. I am at a loss of why this is happening. I think it may have something to do with the line:

> ```
> catchError(error => {
>   return of({
>     type: UserActions.LOGIN_FAILURE,
>     payload: error
>   });
> })
> ```

but here I am lost. I am not an expert on reactive programming, but it all works as it's supposed to except this one case. Does anyone have an idea why this occurs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Effects respect successful completion and errors. In case of an error ngrx will resubscribe, in case case of a successful completion it will not.

For example `catchError` can cause this case, because it doesn't listen to its parent stream. If you want to enable stream in case of an error you need to use `repeat` operator right after `catchError`.

```js
    catchError(error => {
      return of({
        type: UserActions.LOGIN_FAILURE,
        payload: error
      });
    }),
    repeat(), // <- now effect is stable.
```

Answer (score 4):

You will have to add `catchError` on each inner observable, e.g.

```
switchMap(token => this.http.post(environment.apiUrl + '/api/login', { token: token }).pipe(catchError(...)),
```

See the [handling errors](https://ngrx.io/guide/effects#handling-errors) section in the NgRx docs for more info.

Comment: Holy cow, NgRx team member! Thank you :)